# Impossible to enter my password in authentification box

Tags: updates

Since few days, once logged in elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki, when I have to enter my password (for exemple to update), I can't do it because the authentification box is kind of "shaking" with a high frequency and there's two different error messages displayed [image].
The two error messages displayed (translated from french) are:

- incorrect permissions on /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1 (needs to be setuid root)
- identification failed.Try again.

I tried to make a manual update via the terminal but I can't fully complete it (see second screenshot)[image: terminal screenshot]

Thanks for your help.:)

Answer (score 1):

One of your error message is a [known bug](https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/issues/499). Unfortunately there is no workaround yet. You can assign this bug, so you are pinged, when something new happens.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help me. Since then, the situation became fare worse (black screen and strange displays), I reinstall elementary, no problem until now.  :)